# How to get real admin privileges on windows (TrustedInstaller)

Tags: windows-8.1, permissions, user-accounts, administrator, uac

I have an admin user account on my Windows 8.1 machine and I disabled UAC completely and yet I do not have full privileges on my machine.
It happens quite often that I get a dialog saying "You cannot delete/modify this because TrustedInstaller hasn't granted you access"... or something among the lines of that.
This is unacceptable in my opinion. I know what I'm doing and I want access to all my files without constantly having to go through the hassle of changing the ownership of a file.

So how do I get actual admin privileges on my PC? Is there a way to get rid of that TrustedInstaller account thing or tell Windows to use my admin account for that instead?

Comment: 'admin user' is not Administrator. I think your issue stems from that confusion.

Comment: By admin user I meant, that my account type is set to "Administrator".

Comment: That's what I mean, your account type is set to the 'administrators' group, which is not the same as 'administrator' - this may help explain the difference -  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/c23a5d98-3d8b-4391-851d-e5f7922de0c6?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Okay, so if I would log in as "Administrator", I would have all the permissions to delete any files I want? Does the "Administrator" differ in any other way from normal user accounts? Could I just use it as my main user account?

Comment: Administrator is the equivalent of `root`. Yes you can use it as a login account, but it's not wise to do it on a full-time basis.

Comment: Could you elaborate on `not wise`? Is it only not wise because you might accidentally delete a system file? Because I wouldn't do that and I could always roll back; backups ftw.

Comment: It just removes all restrictions; your call - there are many guides on how to enable it - http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/windows-administrator-account-everything-need-know/

Answer (score 1):

You have to take ownership of the files, give your account full write permissiosn to the file/registry key. Now you can modify the files/regitry entry.

There are tools for [Files](http://winaero.com/comment.php?comment.news.18) and [registry](http://winaero.com/comment.php?comment.news.210) that provide this via easy GUI.

[image]

[image]

Do run an Application as TrustedInstaller, start the Windows Module Service, run [ProcessHacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/downloads.php), do a rightlick on `TrustedInstaller.exe`, select msic->run as this user

[image]

Select which process you want to run

[image]

and click on `ok` to start it.

Comment: That sound like the thing that I already have been doing. As I already said, I know that I have to take ownership to delete/modify the files, but I'm looking for a permanent solution so that this isn't necessary anymore.

Comment: Take ownership, change setting, restore permissions back to TrustedInstaller. This is the best way.

Comment: This does not solve my problem.

Comment: sure, you want to ruin your Windows and if I would tell you how to run a cmd.exe as TI you would kill your system and so I don't tell you how to do it. Use this recommend way

Comment: As I already said a couple of times, I know the recommended way. That's not what I came for. I'd simply like to get full permissions because I always know what I'm doing on my system. Something like root access on a Linux system. In Linux I could simply go `sudo su` if I wanted and now nothing would stop me from doing anything. And nothing would break unless the user is stupid. ...Btw, why would running a cmd as TI kill my system?

Comment: I added it. But if you have a damaged Windows I don't help you.

Comment: I still don't understand if you're saying that this would damage my system without any further action or if you're saying that I don't know what I'm doing.

Comment: the 2nd, I doubt that you know what you are doing.

Comment: No offense, but you don't know me. I know what I'm doing. I assume I could simply run explorer.exe as TI and that would pretty much solve my problems? Or are there any side effects to be expected.

Comment: @Forivin there should likely never be a good reason to run explorer or any userspace programs as TrustedInstaller. the side effect is that you're opening up your system to easier exploitation, because you pre-escalated privileges for any malware. Separation of privileges and tbh UAC itself exists for good reasons

Comment: Okay, but I don't download malware, so for me there is no good reason for this to exist.